# Add property name to the property

Tags: javascript, node.js

How effectively convert this json:
`{"person":[["id1","a"],["id2","b"],["id3","c"]]}`

To something like this:

`{"person":[[id: "id1", name: "a"],[id: "id2", name: "b"],[id: "id3", name: "c"]]}`

Basically I don't know how long the output actually would be, but I do know, that the first property is id and second is name, always

Comment: Your desired result is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want an array of objects, since a named array isn't really a thing in JS.

```
let originalData = {"person":[["id1","a"],["id2","b"],["id3","c"]]};
let formattedData = {
    person: originalData.person.map(p => ({id: p[0], name: p[1]}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `[]` Are for **array**: A list of sorted elements with index as key (0, 1, 2, 3...)
- `{}` Are for **object**: A list a pair {key: value}

So `[id: "id1", name: "a"]` is invalid cause you create an array `[]` but you want to use pair key:value (like object `{}`)

If you want an object, with a list of persons on it (array) then with attributes for each of person, each person should be object instead of array `{id:"id1", name:"a"}`:

So you should write:

```
{
  "person": [
    {id: "id1", name: "a"},
    {id: "id2", name: "b"},
    {id: "id3", name: "c"}
  ]
}
```

So:

```
const values = {"person":[["id1","a"],["id2","b"],["id3","c"]]}
// Recreate the list of person by creating a new object for each 
const result = {
  person: values.person.map(p => {id: p[0], name:p[1]})
}
```